# I use await keyword but still get this error, why? >> An asynchronous module or handler > completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I decided to override  `AddToRoleAsync` method of `UserManager` of ASP.NET Identity.

**From:**

```
 public override Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(long userId, string role)
 {
      return base.AddToRoleAsync(userId, role);
 }
```

**To:**

```
 // I added async keyword
 public override async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleAsync(long userId, string role)
 {
      // Adding the await keyword here
      var result = await base.AddToRoleAsync(userId, role); // << It causes the error

      // Calling my appropriate Task method
      await UpdatePermissionsAsync(userId);

      return result;
 }
```

But during debugging process when the program step into `await base.AddToRoleAsync(userId, role)` it dose not continue to the next line of code and when I press `F5`, It return this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: **An asynchronous module or handler
>   completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending**.

I confused because I used `await` keyword before methods that return a `Task` but I still get the error!

**How should I override it?**

---

**Update:**

With following [@StephenCleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s hint, I found an `async void` in the signature of a parent method that was calling above code but itself had not `await` in its caller parent method. So the above problem solved **But** now It made a new problem for me! Because in this case the root method is **`OnAuthorization`** and it should not has `async` keyword (it cause error).

> So I should run my `async` method without `await` inside the 
>   **OnAuthorization** method! **How?**

Comment: This is usually caused by using `async void` somewhere, or calling an EAP method that isn't wrapped in a TAP task.

Comment: Thank you @StephenCleary , your hint about `async void` solved my problem. I found an `async void` in the signature of a parent method that was calling it and itself has not `await` in its parent. **But** now It made a new problem for me! Because in this case the root method is `OnAuthorization` and it should not has `async` keyword (is cause error), So I should run my `async` method without `await` inside the `OnAuthorization` method. _My asks please:_ 
**1)** Write your comment as a an answer
**2)** Guide me how to run my `async` method in `OnAuthorization` method. Thank you in  advance.

Comment: Your update creates confusion in question for future users, I advice that either you post it as a comment under answer or you post a new question, it will be hard to accept two answer :P

Comment: @PetterFriberg, you are right and I know this cause 2 question in 1. But I added it to tell future users why @StephenCleary wrote about `OnAuthorization` in his answer for me. He tried to give me an answer about both of my questions and maybe it is better for  future users to find some solutions about my second problem when it is in the body of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I note in my article on [`async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), this error is usually due to an `async void` method. With `async void`, there is no `Task` returned, so there's no way for your code to `await` its completion.

In your particular case (`OnAuthorization`), unfortunately there isn't a way to do this asynchronously. Also in my [`async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) article, I describe how there are two limitations of `async` support in classic ASP.NET: action filters and child actions. These two cannot safely be made `async` in classic ASP.NET. (ASP.NET Core does allow `async` filters and view components). In this case, `OnAuthorization` is an action filter, and hence cannot be `async`.

The only solutions are to either upgrade to ASP.NET Core and use an `async` action filter, or make your filter synchronous. I recommend making all of the code synchronous, but it is possible to use [some form of sync-over-async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you, I made my filter synchronous.